# Conversion SQL to Jython with list and dict

Tags: python, sql, jython

Trying to convert this script in Jython (which doesn't have pandas)

It uses the tables Work, Budget, Grade, Office.
Now they are no longer tables,

- Work and budget are a List
- Grade and Office are Dictionaries

```html
select
               A.[POS],
               A.[INC],
               A.[EMPL],
               A.[COMP] ,
               A.[EmplStatus] ,
               A.[HRStatus] ,
               A.[FTE] ,
               A.[FCCODE],
        P.Job,
               A.[WageLossPlan],
               P.BCC,
        P.[BargainingUnit],
        P.[STHOURSPDAY] ,
               A.[HRRATE] ,
               A.[SALCODE] ,
               A.[SALSTEP],
               SG.GRADE,
               SG.NUMBSTEPS,
               A.[ENTRYDATE],
               A.[HOLSCHEDULECODE] ,
               A.[UNI]
from Work A, Budget P, Grade SG, Office J
where
P.Job=J.Job and
J.Grade=SG.Grade and
A.Pos=P.Pos and
A.EffectiveDate = (Select Max(Efftdate) from Work
                   where Inc=A.Inc and
                         Pos= A.Pos )
```

Work

```html
INC|POS|EMPL|COMP|EMPLSTATUS|HRSTATUS|FTE|GRADE|WAGELOSSPLAN|FCCODE|JOB|HRRATE|SALCODE|SALSTEP|ENTRYDATE|UNI|STHOURSPDAY|HOLSCHEDULECODE|EFFTDATE|ENDDATE|EFFTSTATUS
0024425|00027376|0|MO|A|A|1|C47|LOW|MOCC713406610|100042||NON-C47-10|10|01-APR-2013|C|7.5|H12F75|01-APR-2013|01-JAN-9999|A
0024425|00027376|0|MO|A|A|1|C47|LOW|MOCC713406610|100042||NON-C47-10|10|01-APR-2013|C|7.5|H12F75|01-APR-2012|31-MAR-2013|A
0046974|00029012|0|MO|A|A|1|C47|LOW|MOCO711790000|100042||NON-C47-6|6|01-APR-2022|C|7.5|H12F75|11-MAR-2022|01-JAN-9999|A
```

Budget

```html
COMP|POS|DESCRLONG|DESCRSHORT|FCCODE|JOBC|FULLTIMEFLAG|FILLEDFLAG|BUDGETEDFLAG|FTE|TYPECODE|EFFTSTATUS|EFFTDATE|ENDDATE|UNI|DescrLong|BARGAINUNIT|STHOURSPDAY
MO|00027376|Academic, Med Ed|Academic C|MOCC713406610|100042|F|1|Y|1|G|A|01-APR-2013|01-JAN-9999|C|MOS|NON|7.5
MO|00029012|Trans|Translatio|MOCO711790000|100042|F|1|Y|1|G|A|11-MAR-2022|01-JAN-9999|C|MOS|NON|7.5
```

Grade

```html
GRADE|SALPLANCODE|DESCRLONG|DESCRSHORT|EFFTDATE|EFFTSTATUS|NUMBSTEPS
C47|NON|C47 - Eff dt: 2022-04-01|C47|01-APR-2022|A|10
C48|NON|C48 - Eff dt: 2022-04-01|C48|01-APR-2022|A|10
```

Office

```html
JOB|BCC|UNI|GRADE|DESCRLONG|DESCRSHORT|EFFTDATE|EFFTSTATUS
100042|1|C|C47|Coordinator 7|Coordinato,01-JAN-01,A
101830|1|C|C47|Secretary 7|Secretary,01-JAN-01,A
101831|1|C|C47|Coordinator 7|Coordinato,01-JAN-01,A
101832|1|C|C47|Officer 7|Officer 7,01-JAN-01,A
101833|1|C|C47|Analyst 7|Analyst 7,01-JAN-01,A
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I'm  not sure what your question is. Is there a problem with your query, or do you need help converting your result to lists and dictionaries?